# Error 91 occurring during iterations randomly

Tags: vba, excel

Interesting problem here.  This line of  code works through multiple iterations until it reaches a point where it throws an Run-time error 91 at me: "Object Variable or With block variable not set".  This is occurring in a function designed to find a deal number.  The entire program is an end of day email generation program that sends attachments to various different counter-parties.  The error occurs on the ** line. For additional color, temp deal is not empty when execution is attempted.  There doesn't appear to be any extraneous trailing or leading spaces either. Thanks in advance!

```
    Function getPDFs(cFirm As Variant, iFirm As Variant, row_counter As Variant, reportsByFirm As Worksheet, trMaster As Worksheet, trSeparate As Variant, trName As Variant, reportDate As Variant) As String

    dealCol = 1
    Dim locationArray() As String
    Dim DealArray() As String
    cDes = "_vs._NY"
    iDes = "_vs._IC"
    filePath = "X:\Office\Confirm Drop File\"
    dealNum = reportsByFirm.Cells(row_counter, dealCol)
    FileType = ".pdf"

    If InStr(1, dealNum, "-") > 0 Then

        DealArray() = Split(dealNum, "-")
        tempDeal = DealArray(LBound(DealArray))

    Else
        tempDeal = dealNum

    End If

    'Finds deal location in spread sheet for further detail to obtain file path
    **trLocation = trMaster.Columns(2).Find(What:=tempDeal).Address
    locationArray() = Split(trLocation, "$")
    trRow = locationArray(UBound(locationArray))

    'Formats client names for 20 characters and removes punctuation (".") in order to stay within convention of file naming
    cFirmFormatted = Trim(Left(cFirm, 20))
    iFirmFormatted = Trim(Left(iFirm, 20))

    'Finds clearing method
    clMethod = trMaster.Cells(trRow, 6).Value

    Select Case clmethod
        Case "Clport"

            'Prevents naming convention issues with punctuations in the name
            If InStr(1, cFirmFormatted, ".") > 0 Then
                cFirmFormatted = Replace(cFirmFormatted, ".", "")
            End If

            getPDFs = filePath & cFirmFormatted & "\" & reportDate & "_" & dealNum & "_" & cFirmFormatted & cDes & FileType

        Case "ICE"

            If InStr(1, iFirmFormatted, ".") > 0 Then
                iFirmFormatted = Replace(iFirmFormatted, ".", "")
            End If

            getPDFs = filePath & iFirmFormatted & "\" & reportDate & "_" & dealNum & "_" & iFirmFormatted & iDes & FileType
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: you dim TrMaster as worksheet, but you don't assign a value to it using set. Or is it a global variable?

Comment: Luuklag TrMaster is passed in as a parameter from the main Sub.  Does it still need to be set in the function even though it is set in the sub?

Comment: try adding an `After` argument to the `Find` function to ensure it searches from the top down each time:  `trMaster.Columns(2).Find(What:=tempDeal, After:=trMaster.Cells(1,2)).Address
` Furthemore, ensure you declare `dealNum` and `tempDeal` as String variables.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Just gave that a try.  Error still persisting.  Unsure why it would randomly show up after multiple successful iterations.

Comment: @StormsEdge, please see my additional comment that I just editing in. It's **best** practice to **always** declare all variable types as *specifically* as possible.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Done!  That makes a lot of sense.  Still have the error, but can see why that's a lot safer.

Comment: where is trLocation defined? what type is it, if it is an object then you should use "set" to assign it.

Comment: @StormsEdge - that goes for `trLocation` as well. But see @MacroMans answer below. He's got a great point, as well. :) I was kind of assuming that you always knew the value would be with there ... which probably was a wrong assumption!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The value should always be found.  The value is being referenced from a sheet that pulls it from trMaster at a different point in the spreadsheet so it's mere existence indicates that it should be found, but it's best practice indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code assumes that `trLocation` is always found, if it isn't found then you will receive an error because you don't have a range to return the `.Address` property for.

Try testing the result first:

```
Dim testLocation As Excel.Range

Set testLocation = trMaster.Columns(2).Find(tempDeal)

If Not testLocation Is Nothing Then
    trLocation = testLocation.Address
    '// Rest of code here...
Else
    MsgBox "Cannot find """ & tempDeal & """!"
    Exit Function
End If
```

Comment: great point @Macro Man. I was thinking about this but was assuming OP *knew* that the value would be there for sure. One point in your code, shouldn't `trLocation = trLocation.Address` be `trLocation = testLocation.Address`?

Comment: Yes it should! good spot ;) I was ***obviously*** just making sure you were paying attention! haha

Comment: This is a great suggestion and a good addition to the code either way, but still experiencing the error =[.  Thank you though!  Still getting stuck on same line of execution.  Also, just for further color, the deal number will always exist.  It wouldn't be initialized to search for it if it didn't exist in the first place.  Luckily the sheet i'm building off of has some good chains of logic built into it.

Comment: @StormsEdge If you've used my code then you shouldn't have that line anymore?

Comment: @MacroMan Sorry!  I had a typo in the code lol.  It worked as we would expect.  It posts that it cannot find the temp deal, but the problem is that I am looking at the temp deal number.  It definitely exists.  Any idea why that might be?  Thank you for all of your help by the way!

Comment: Obviously I don't know what the format of the number is but look for any extra spaces before/after the number or check the formatting of the column _(i.e. make sure it's not formatted as "Text")_ - If it's a whole number try using something like `CLng(Trim(tempDeal))` - there ***will*** be a difference _(Excel doesn't have the ability to just 'not like' something!)._ You just need to find it! :)

Comment: @MacroMan Haha that's true!  Imagine how much trouble I might have if it had a temperament....It would be ignoring me for forgetting to Dim all of my variables! =p.  I tried CLng(Trim(tempDeal)) and that didn't seem to fix the problem.  I am looking at the columns and it's formatted as "general number".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98824/discussion-between-macro-man-and-stormsedge).